# angular list item active (ng-click)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i am trying to add / remove a class from a list item all depending on a variable: (Note if there is a better of doing this active thing please let me know :P )

So my code looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="fold in folds" class="{{selectedFolder == fold.filter ?  'active' : ''}}">
    <a ng-click="selectedFolder = fold.filter">
        {{fold.name}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Now when i click the first one the `class` is added however once i click the next one the old `class` is not replaced by `''` instead now two `li` has the `class` `active`

Can anyone  tell me why?

Comment: remove `class`, add `ng-class="{'active' :  selectedFolder == fold.filter}"`

Comment: this is AngularJS... I think Angular it's called when i'ts Angular 2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<li ng-repeat="fold in folds" ng-class="{'active' :  selectedFolder == fold.filter}">
    .....
</li>
```

this will add the css class `active` to  the `li` element when `selectedFolder == fold.filter` is sets to `true`, IF `selectedFolder == fold.filter` is sets to `false` then `active` class is remove from the `li` element.

if you need to toggle the css class `add & remove` when clicking, I think you can remove the `.. ng-click="selectedFolder = fold.filter"...` part and replace it with `ng-click="selectedFolder = !selectedFolder"` and change the `ng-class` to `ng-class="{'active' :  selectedFolder == 1}` and add `ng-init="selectedFolder = 0"` to the `li`, This will add a variable to `ng-repeat` scope so that each repeat has its own `selectedFolder` variable in its scope *`(ng-repeat creates a child scope)`*.

when click in `<a>` we can toggle the value of `selectedFolder` so that will toggle the `css class` `..<a ng-click="selectedFolder = !selectedFolder">..`

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8IAkNmC4xGXkeUox3pRK?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

to having one `active` element.

create a variable to refer the active element. (I used object because its easy to refer from the `ng-repeat` because `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, so we cant directly call if this variable is just a primitive variable if its primitive we have to use `$parent.variable_name`), So its easy to use a object to represent it.

```
 $scope.active = {
    elm : -1
 }
```

when click on `<a>` assign the `$index` value to `active.elm`

```
<a ng-click="active.elm = $index">
..
```

`$index` is the `ng-repeat` index just like

for first repeat `$index is equals to 0`
for second repeat `$index is equals to 1`.. like wise.

change `ng-class` to, this will add class `active` when `active.elm == $index` set to `true`.

```
..ng-class="{'active' :  active.elm == $index}">
...
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JflSHBq5Pn8Mhs695mWH?p=preview)

Comment: Hey thanks for your response but is there a way to only allow 1 to have the "active" class ? in your example i get the same result as i have right now which allows more than one list item to be active

Answer (score 0):

use ng-class

```
<li ng-repeat="fold in folds" ng-class="{{selectedFolder == fold.filter ?  'active' : ''}}">
    <a ng-click="selectedFolder = fold.filter">
        {{fold.name}}
    </a>
</li>
```